# TypeError: string indices must be integers Python 2

Tags: python-2.7, typeerror, pubmed

I am using python 2.7 and getting an error at

> print 'Article ID: ', paper['MedlineCitation']['PMID']

the error is TypeError

> Article ID: 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "F:/Practicals/Pubmed/pubmed-master/pubmed-master/scrap_pubmed.py", line 44, in 
>       print 'Article ID: ', paper['MedlineCitation']['PMID']
>   TypeError: string indices must be integers

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Enter keyword to search for: "
    keyword = raw_input()
    print "Enter number # of articles to fetch (number): "
    number_of_articles = raw_input()
    results = search(keyword, number_of_articles)
    id_list = results['IdList']
    papers = fetch_details(id_list)
    filename = 'pubmed.txt'
    target = open(filename, 'w')

    for i, paper in enumerate(papers):
        number_of_authors = 0
        print 'Article ID: ', paper['MedlineCitation']['PMID']
        target.write('Article ID: ' + paper['MedlineCitation']['PMID'] + '\n')

        print 'ISSN No: ', paper['MedlineCitation']['Article']['Journal']['ISSN']
        target.write('ISSN No: ' + paper['MedlineCitation'][
                     'Article']['Journal']['ISSN'] + '\n')
```

Comment: variable paper is a string object! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are looping it wrong.

You have to access the dictionary object by giving the el as key.

Like this:

```
  for i, paper in enumerate(papers):
    print papers[paper][0]['MedlineCitation']['PMID']
```

Comment: thank you brother. i have another issue with now. It only gives me one record, if i want more then one record it gives me IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Thats because the list does not have that much records that you are trying to access.